# ViewModel with SavedStateHandle - exception when LiveData with custom data class is being deserialized

Tags: android, viewmodel, android-livedata, parcelable, viewmodel-savedstate

I have a simple `ViewModel` which gets the `SavedStateHandle`. This `ViewModel` has single `LiveData` that hold `MyViewState<List<MyDataClass>>`, which is as follows:

```
sealed class MyViewState<T> : Parcelable {
    @Parcelize data class ErrorState<T>(val error: @RawValue Any?): MyViewState<T>()
    @Parcelize data class SuccessState<T>(val data: @RawValue T): MyViewState<T>()
}
```

and

```
@Parcelize data class MyDataClass(val data: String): Parcelable
```

The `LiveData` in the `ViewModel` is retrieved like this:

```
class MyViewModel(
    private val handle: SavedStateHandle
): ViewModel() {

    var myLiveData = handle.getLiveData<MyViewState<List<MyDataClass>>>("myLiveData")
    ...
}
```

And this works great. However once the app gets killed and I switch back to it, the app crashes with this exception:

```
E/Parcel: Class not found when unmarshalling: com.myapp.models.MyDataClass
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.myapp.models.MyDataClass
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:453)
        at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator(Parcel.java:2811)
        at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2765)
        at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2668)
        at android.os.Parcel.readListInternal(Parcel.java:3098)
        at android.os.Parcel.readArrayList(Parcel.java:2319)
        at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2689)
        at com.myapp.core.MyViewState$Success$Creator.createFromParcel(Unknown Source:13)
        ...
```

...and I can't figure out why would this crash happen and how to solve it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like a bug in `SavedStateRegistry`. They get a `Bundle` but they don't set the correct class loader. Reading the source code, the only way I can think of is to wait for it to get restored and then hijack the restored bundle via reflection to call `setClassLoader` on it.

Comment: I wonder whether this could have something to do with the type being `@RawValue` in the `MyViewState.Success` sealed class? It does seem to work fine if the inner `data` list is empty

Comment: did you get any useful answers?